# WPF nested ItemsControl binding issue

Tags: wpf

Why is the second ItemsControl binding to FirstName not working?

```
 <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PMItmsControl" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstEntityCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="YellowGreen" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5">
                        <Grid Width="auto" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="60*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock **x:Name="tb"** Width="100" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Text="{Binding FirstName}" FontSize="10" >
                            </TextBlock>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SecondEntityCollection}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SecondName}" Margin="5"  Foreground="White" />
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding **Path= Text, ElementName=tb**}" Margin="5" Width="40">
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

and in my code behind, i declare following classes:

```
public class FirstEntity 
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<SecondEntity> SecondEntityCollection { get; set; }
    }

    public class SecondEntity
    {
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
    }
```

and the FirstEntityCollection is declare as following in my code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<FirstEntity> FirstEntityCollection {get;set;}
```

not sure if i make my issue clear?
can someone give me any idea? please.

### thanks much. very appreciate.

updated: I just found another solution use x:Name="tb" to above Bold code. and then changes Text="{Binding Path= DataContext.FirstName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl},AncestorLevel=2}}" to Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=tb}"

thanks Maxi.

----------------updated again-------------
this is the first time I asked question in stackoverflow, the question editor is not easy to input code and comments and the formatting is so bad, maybe I don't find a easy way to use. anyway thanks.

Comment: <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path= DataContext.FirstName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl},AncestorLevel=2}}" Margin="5" Width="40">

Comment: What is `DataContext` of the parent `ItemsControl` and how the `FirstName` property is defined there?

Comment: @Maxim, public class FirstEntity 
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public SecondEntity SecondEntity { get; set; }
    }
 
    public class SecondEntity
    {
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
    }

Comment: `FirstEntity` is not a data context of the parent `ItemsControl`. It's a property of it. Show me your view-model that contains `FirstEntity` and `FirstName` properties.

Comment: Please update the question and do not add code and vital information to the comments.

Comment: i just bind the parent ItemsControl 's ItemsSource to

Comment: @Maxim I just bind the parent ItemsControl's ItemsSource to public ObservableCollection<FirstEntity> FirstEntityCollection

Comment: I didn't ask you about `ItemsSource`. I asked you about `DataContext`. What is the data context of the parent `ItemsControl`?

Comment: @Maxim I did not set any DataContext, just default.

Comment: Default `DataContext` is `null`. If you set `ItemsSource="{Binding FirstEntity}"` that `FirstEntity` is a property of the type used as `DataContext`. Seems that you don't understand binding and its source, learn WPF basics.

Comment: @Jacob_Tan Can you show us the collection structure you are binding to DataContext?

Comment: @Maxim it is a typo, i set ItemsSource="{Binding FirstEntityCollection}" not "FirstEntity". public ObservableCollection<FirstEntity> FirstEntityCollection {get;set;}

Comment: I ask you again: **What the type has property called FirstEntityCollection?** Where this property is declared?

Comment: @Maxim just code behind xxx.cs file. not viewmodel file. the "FirstEntityCollection" is declared in code behind. I have updated my post, please help to review. thanks much.

Comment: Please don't use code snippets. They don't work with C# and XAML.

Comment: Your `Binding Path=DataContext.FirstName` refers to `FirstName` property of the `DataContext` of the parent `ItemsControl`. You said that `DataContext` is just your window. If you have not `FirstName` property in code-behind how do you suppose your binding will work? It can't find `FirstName` property because your `DataContext` hasn't it.

Comment: @Maxim GOT IT. thanks dude, I am new to WPF.

Answer (score 0):

The first mess-up you need to get rid of is setting `Foreground="White"` on the `TextBlock`.

Based on your question update, please find below XAML bindings.

```
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PMItmsControl" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstEntityCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="YellowGreen" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5">
                    <Grid Width="auto" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Text="{Binding FirstName}" FontSize="10" >
                        </TextBlock>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SecondEntityCollection}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SecondName}" Margin="5"  />
                                        <!--Notice setting DataContext to TextBlock below-->
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Text="{Binding Path= FirstName}" Margin="5" Width="Auto"/>                                        </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Hope this give you an idea to start with...

Comment: I already updated. I did not set DataContext. just set parent ItemsControl's ItemsSource to FirstEntityCollection. can you review my post and give me any idea. thanks very much.

Comment: Without setting DataContext how you are getting data to ItemsSource? You need to revisit your code.

Comment: Still your updated question is not clear what and how you are trying to do it. I suggest you get an understanding of the binding from my answer and work back on your binding learning and then change it according to your requirement.

Comment: in code behind file, the construction function have "this.DataContext=this."

Comment: Do you think that your code `this.DataContext=this` equals your phrase `I did not set DataContext`? You could get help much time ago if you show what people ask you about.